# Can you put a CREATE TABLE statement inside a PL/SQL block?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I am trying to write some code to check if a table exists before creating it. To start off, I am trying to run the following:

```
BEGIN 
create table IT.DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REG_TABLE
(
  agentname        VARCHAR2(100) not null,
  servername       VARCHAR2(100) not null,
  datelastdeployed TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE,
  technology       VARCHAR2(100) not null,
  issetup          VARCHAR2(10)
);
EXCEPTION
  NULL;
END;/
```

However, it appears that this is not valid PL/SQL code. Does anyone know why this might be the case? Is there some distinction between DDL and DML for PL/SQL?

Comment: The `exception` block is malformed. If you meant, `... exception when others then null; ...`, stop doing that!!

Comment: PL/SQL will only parse DML, not DDL. So DDL needs to be wrapped in a string and passed to the SQL engine. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and DBMS_SQL are two ways of doing so.

Comment: The need to create a table in a plsql block is not a common requirement. The ddl is usually created and executed on its own. There are a few examples on s.o.  if you need to do this in a plsql block.

Comment: Yes it can be but why? There e are much easier ways. You indicate sqldeveloper so expand the tables list and see if the table you want is there; use the DESC command; select the table name from the ..._tables view; just run the create - you'll get an error if it exists.

Comment: Thanks Shannon and Patrick for answering the "why". I need to do this as part of our automation initiative, but I agree, it definitely seems against industry practice to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a block like this:

```
DECLARE 
  L_CNT PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(0)
  INTO L_CNT
  FROM ALL_TABLES T
  WHERE T.TABLE_NAME = 'DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REG_TABLE'
      AND T.OWNER = 'IT';

  IF L_CNT > 0 THEN
    RETURN;
  END IF;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table IT.DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REG_TABLE' || chr(10) ||
                    '(' || chr(10) ||
                    '  agentname        VARCHAR2(100) not null,' || chr(10) ||
                    '  servername       VARCHAR2(100) not null,' || chr(10) ||
                    '  datelastdeployed TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE,' || chr(10) ||
                    '  technology       VARCHAR2(100) not null,' || chr(10) ||
                    '  issetup          VARCHAR2(10)' || chr(10) ||
                    ')';

END;
```

Comment: Good suggestion, using "all_tables"

Comment: All the answers were great and I upvoted all of them, but I liked this one since it got around the exception in a pretty elegant fashion and explains stuff about ALL_TABLES

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it using dynamic SQL, i.e. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

However, think twice - creating tables that way isn't usual. Why would you want to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The common exception that oracle throws is "ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object". But this alone is insufficient to tell that the table is already created. Due to the fact that within the same namespace, no two objects can have the same name:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#i78631

Hence the exception message: "name is already used by an existing object"

But if you are aware of that and want an anonymous pl/sql block:

```
declare
  lc__    constant varchar2(100) := 'Anonymous PL/SQL Block';
  already_created  exception;
  pragma exception_init(already_created, -955);  -- ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
  lv_stmt          varchar2(32767);
begin
  lv_stmt := q'[create table it.devops_uc_server_reg_table (
                  agentname        varchar2(100) not null,
                  servername       varchar2(100) not null,
                  datelastdeployed timestamp(6) with time zone,
                  technology       varchar2(100) not null,
                  issetup          varchar2(10))
               ]';
  begin
    execute immediate lv_stmt;
  exception
    when already_created then
      dbms_output.put_line('Name already defined on an existing object');
    when others then
      raise;
  end;
exception when others then
  raise_application_error(-20777, lc__ || chr(10) || dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks for all the great answers. I decided to combine them, and this is what I used ultimately:

```
DECLARE 
  L_CNT PLS_INTEGER;
  lv_stmt varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  --Check if the table already exists 
  SELECT COUNT(0)
  INTO L_CNT
  FROM ALL_TABLES T
  WHERE T.TABLE_NAME = 'DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REG_TABLE'
      AND T.OWNER = 'IT';
  IF L_CNT > 0 THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('The table already exists');
    RETURN;
  END IF;

  --Check if the constraint already exists
  SELECT COUNT(0)
  INTO L_CNT
  FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS C
  WHERE C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'DEVOPS_UC_Server_Reg_PKEY'
      AND C.OWNER = 'IT';
  IF L_CNT > 0 THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('The primary key constraint already exists');
    RETURN;
  END IF;

  dbms_output.put_line('Creating table...');


  /*
 this code is auto-generated from DBMS_METADATA. It was accessed using the following query:

SELECT 
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL( 'TABLE','DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REG_TABLE','IT') 
FROM DUAL;

 so long as the tables do not exist, and the PRIMARY KEY NAME does not already exist 
 then this will create the table with the primary key constraint. 
 otherwise, you will run into ORA-0095: name already used by existing object (if table exists)
 or ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
 TODO: make the table name and primary key constraint name variables for ease of use/robustness 
*/
  lv_stmt:=q'[
  CREATE TABLE "IT"."DEVOPS_UC_SERVER_REG_TABLE" 
   (    "AGENTNAME" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SERVERNAME" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DATELASTDEPLOYED" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE, 
    "TECHNOLOGY" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ISSETUP" VARCHAR2(10 CHAR), 
     CONSTRAINT "DEVOPS_UC_Server_Reg_PKEY" PRIMARY KEY ("AGENTNAME", "SERVERNAME", "TECHNOLOGY")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "IT"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "IT" ]';

    execute immediate lv_stmt;
dbms_output.put_line('Table created successfully');

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you with a MSSQL background, you have probably come across a situation or two where you wished Oracle had an equivalent for the `IF NOT EXISTS() CREATE TABLE()` syntax. My release  needed to create a table named A_OBF_Key in the CRUSHER schema. Another in-flight release also wanted to create that same table (with the same structure). We did not know which release would be deployed first, and frankly it didn't matter. We did not want to introduce a dependency between the two releases, but the customer did not want to see a "TABLE ALREADY EXISTS" error from whichever release was deployed second.

For those leery of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, there is a way to script this for SQLPlus using Oracle meta data, a SQLPlus variable, and two files: one that gets executed if the table exists, and one that gets executed if the table does not exist.

I already had a file named "OBF_Key.sql" that created the A_OBF_Key table:

```
/* OBF_Key.sql */

PROMPT Handle OBF_Key objects...
    PROMPT ... table
        CREATE TABLE CRUSHER.A_OBF_Key(
            KEY_NAME            VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
            KEY_VALUE           VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL,
            DESCRIPTION         VARCHAR2(500) ,
            SITE_CD             VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL,
            EFFECTIVE_DTE       DATE NOT NULL,
            EXPIRE_DTE          DATE ,
            DATA_ENTRY_USER_ID  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
            DATA_ENTRY_DTE      DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL
        );
```

I also already had a coordinating file named "run_me_first.sql" that called OBF_Key.sql. I created an additional file "OBF_Key_Exists.sql" that would handle the case when A_OBF_Key was already created:

```
/* OBF_Key_Exists.sql */

PROMPT ...something else already installed OBF_Key, so moving on...
```

I then edited run_me_first.sql to

1. set define on
2. set scan on
3. declare a sqlplus variable
4. populate that variable based on the existence of A_OBF_Key
5. Change the script execution from hard-coded "OBF_Key.sql" to the value of the variable assigned in step 4
6. set scan off
7. set define off

Like this:

```
/* run_me_first.sql */

SET DEFINE ON;
SET scan on;

COLUMN script_to_run NEW_VALUE script_to_run_now

PROMPT Check OBF_Key objects...
    /* will return 'OBF_Key_Exists.sql' if the table is already created, or 'OBF_Key.sql' if it is not yet created */
    SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 'OBF_Key_Exists.sql' ELSE 'OBF_Key.sql' END AS script_to_run
    FROM All_Tables
    WHERE UPPER(owner) = 'CRUSHER'
        AND UPPER(table_name) = 'A_OBF_Key';

    --run the file named after the variable populated with the above query
    @@&script_to_run_now

    --these things I want to do whether or not the table already existed
    GRANT SELECT ON CRUSHER.A_OBF_Key TO SECURITY;
    GRANT SELECT ON CRUSHER.OBF_Key TO SECURITY;
    CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM SECURITY.OBF_Key FOR CRUSHER.OBF_Key;

--put session settings back the way we started
SET scan off;
SET DEFINE OFF;
```